# Extracting rows based on multiple variables within the same column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I've got a very large dataframe, `data` (with > 200,000 rows), containing genomic positions for different genes. I want to extract all rows based on different genes and combine them into a new dataframe. For example, I want all rows for `SSR1` and `STK38`.

```
chrom  txStart ExonCount geneSymbol
chr6   7281287         8       SSR1
chr6   7295624         8       SSR1
chr6   7298155         8       SSR1
chr6  31938951         8      STK19
chr6  31939645         8      STK19
chr6  31940397         8      STK19
chr6  36461668        14      STK38
chr6  36464487        14      STK38
chr6  36465556        14      STK38
chr6 125229391         7        STL
chr6 125241333         7        STL
chr6 125252841         7        STL
```

Of course, I could do this using the `which` like below, and then combine them using `rbind`, but that's too time consuming since I'll be having a lot of genes.

```
Gene1 <- data[which(data$geneSymbol=="SSR1"), ]
Gene2 <- data[which(data$geneSymbol=="STK38"), ]
```

I've tried a `for` loop, but I'm not getting the right output.

```
genes1 <- 0
genes <- c("SSR1", "STK38")
for (i in genes) {
  genes1 <- print(data[which(data$geneSymbol==i), ])
}
```

I want it too look like this:

```
chrom  txStart ExonCount geneSymbol
chr6   7281287         8       SSR1
chr6   7295624         8       SSR1
chr6   7298155         8       SSR1
chr6  36461668        14      STK38
chr6  36464487        14      STK38
chr6  36465556        14      STK38
```

I'm sure that the solution is very easy, but I've looked all over the web for the past few days without finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==` for greater than one element

```
subset(data, geneSymbol %in% c("SSR1", "STK38"))
#   chrom  txStart ExonCount geneSymbol
#1  chr6  7281287         8       SSR1
#2  chr6  7295624         8       SSR1
#3  chr6  7298155         8       SSR1
#7  chr6 36461668        14      STK38
#8  chr6 36464487        14      STK38
#9  chr6 36465556        14      STK38
```

---

As the dataset is big, we can also do `data.table` methods for subsetting.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', set the 'key' column and subset the rows where the 'geneSymbol' is either 'SSR1" or "STK38".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data, key = "geneSymbol")[.(c("SSR1", "STK38"))]
#   chrom  txStart ExonCount geneSymbol
#1:  chr6  7281287         8       SSR1
#2:  chr6  7295624         8       SSR1
#3:  chr6  7298155         8       SSR1
#4:  chr6 36461668        14      STK38
#5:  chr6 36464487        14      STK38
#6:  chr6 36465556        14      STK38
```

Comment: Please study the FAQ [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled): "In a nutshell: If a question is a duplicate of another question, flag or vote to close."; "Should I answer it? No, not if you think it's a duplicate".

Comment: Please also read [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/): "**Don't answer questions that have already been answered elsewhere**. Yeah, you might earn a couple of points of reputation, but, because you are duplicating content, _you are actually making the internet worse._".

Comment: @Henrik THe OP's dataset is really big and your dupe link doesn't provide that option, where as my solution also have data.table

Comment: @ akrun - thanks a million. I had tried the subset but without the %in% i didn't get far!!!

Comment: @Henrik, I had looked at various discussions and also went through the  suggested questions when formulating my question, but whatever i was looking for, i couldn't find!